# How to get Powershell result from inner start-processs

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a ps script like:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "Get-WebApplication"
```

Because Get-WebApplication needs admin right, so I use "-verb runAs".

My question is: now the result only shows in the new powershell windows. How can I make my main powershell get/display the result?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices that I see:

1. Run your script as administrator and just run Get-WebApplication directly.
2. Capture the output from the powershell process you're starting with Start-process and then do whatever you want with the output in your script. To capture the output you can either redirect the output to a file and then read the file in your script, or you can use .NET `[diagnostics.process]::start` to redirect stdout and directly read the output stream in your script (no file is created).

Comment: Hi, I did use .net to call PS, which means (1) is not working. Also for (2), I am not using diagnostics, but use Runspace & Pipeline. Then how can I capture?

Comment: @Samuel I don't understand what you mean. In 1. I'm saying to run powershell as the administrator. Then run Get-WebApplication within that Powershell: `Get-WebApplication` instead of the code in the OP. If for some reason you can't do that, then search google for how to use `[diagnostics.process]::start` from within Powershell.